# DomPDF con tablas repetidas

Tags: php

He creado un reporte con [`dompdf`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). Tengo 4 consultas pero cuando ejecuto se me repiten mis tablas 2 veces, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'pass', 'gOtyqQAJ', 'atencionin_vih2');

    //obtenemos el valor de la id desde la url y la asignamos a un variable
$id = $_GET['id'];  
        //consulta que permite ubicar toda la información el usuario con id = $id
$query = "SELECT * FROM resultado WHERE cuestionario_idpaciente =" .$id;
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){//si la consulta devuelve informacion
    while($user3[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); //recorremos el resultado y lo asignamos a un array asociativo '$user'

}
//cerrar conexion a bbdd
mysqli_close($link);    


 $html .= ' <form action="" method="post" name="busca_paciente" id="busca_paciente" >

      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
             <th COLSPAN="13" >RESULTADOS</th>
        </tr>   
    <tr>

        <th>VIH 1ra:</th>
        <th>VIH 2da:</th>
        <th>Sífilis:</th>
        <th>VDRL:</th>
        <th>Tuberculosis xpert: </th>
        <th>Gonorrea:</th>
        <th>Clamidia:</th>
        <th>Hepatitis B:</th>
        <th>Hepatitis C:</th>
        <th>Resistencia:</th>
        <th>Carga Viral:</th>
        <th>CD 4 :</th>
        <th>Fecha de Vinculación:</th>

    </tr>';

    foreach ($user3 as $resultado3) {

$html .='<tr>

        <td>'.$resultado3['vih_1ra'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['vih_2da'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['sifilis'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['vdrl'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['xpert'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['gonorrea'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['clamidia'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['hepatitis_b'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['hepatitis_c'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['resistencia'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['carga_viral'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['cd_4'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado3['fecha_vincu'].'</td>

    </tr> ';
    }
$html .='</table>
 </form>
 <hr>';

//conexion a bbdd
//include('conexserv.php');
//$con= conectar();

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'atencionin', 'pass', 'atencionin_vih2');

    //obtenemos el valor de la id desde la url y la asignamos a un variable
$id = $_GET['id'];  
        //consulta que permite ubicar toda la información el usuario con id = $id
$query = "SELECT * FROM solomedico WHERE cuestionario_idpaciente =" .$id;
if($result = mysqli_query($link,$query)){//si la consulta devuelve informacion
    while($user4[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); //recorremos el resultado y lo asignamos a un array asociativo '$user'       
}
//cerrar conexion a bbdd
mysqli_close($link);    


 $html .='<form action="" method="post" name="busca_paciente" id="busca_paciente" >

            <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
             <th COLSPAN="12" >DATOS MEDICOS</th>
        </tr>   
      <tr>

        <th>Número de Folio:</th>
        <th>Nombre(s):</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno:</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno:</th>
        <th>¿Conoce la fecha aproximada de la infección por VIH?:</th>
        <th>Confirmacion de la infección por VIH:</th>
        <th>Tipo de prueba de confirmación, (especifique):</th>
        <th>Presenta síntomas clínicos o cursa con alguna enfermedad?:</th>
        <th>¿qué síntomas o enfermedad?:</th>
        <th>Está tomando algun medicamento,(excluyendo arvs)?:</th>
        <th>¿cuáles?:</th>
        <th>Estado clínico de la infeccion por VIH:</th>


    </tr>';  

     foreach ($user4 as $resultado4) {  

$html .=' <tr> 

        <td>'.$resultado4['numfolio'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['p_nombre'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['apellido_p'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['apellido_m'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['fecha_aprox'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['confirm_infec'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['prue_confirm'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['pres_sin_clini'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['sint_enfer'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['toma_algu_medi'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['cuales'].'</td>
        <td>'.$resultado4['esta_cli_infec'].'</td>

    </tr>';
     }

$html  .='</table>   
      </form>
       </div> 
        </body>
          </html> ';

     require_once ('libpdf/mpdf.php');   
    $mpdf = new mPDF('c','A2');
    //$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;   // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
    $css = file_get_contents('libpdf/estilospdf/estilopdf.css');
    $mpdf ->writeHTML($css , 1);
    $mpdf ->writeHTML ($html,2);
    $mpdf ->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: como se ve el html resultado??

Comment: el html esta bien la tabla se imprime con la pregunta y respuesta desde la base de datos el problema  es que cada seccion se repite dos veces lo raro es que la primera se imprime con pregunta y respuesta pero la segunda que viene siendo la copia solo se imprime con las preguntas ya no salen las respuestas

Comment: cambie el nombre de las consultas para que no sean iguales y aun asi siguen saliendo las tablas o formularios repetidos